how to add custom variable to no code paypal button?
I have a no code button (smart button) with ipn set up for it. How can I add the custom variable to the link of my button?
I tried adding ?custom=myidhere to the button link, however in my ipn server, it still shows custom: ''
I also tried ?custom_id=myidhere

At this time the No Code button does not support passing any type of dynamically-set custom variable. The only available inputs must be set using the fields provided by the No Code button UI itself.

then what should I use instead?

Depends on your needs, the standard integration with a backend offers the most functionality https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/
